# Создание нескольких элементов с помощью $.each()

Tags: jquery, json, javascript

Мне нужно написать функцию в 
`$.each()` что бы она создавала на лту несколько элементов
вот что я набросил примерно

```
$.getJSON( url + "&callback=?",     
function(data){
     $.each(data.data, function(i,item){
        $("<div class='img-page'></div>").html($("<img class='fix' />").attr('src', item.images.thumbnail.url)).appendTo(".clickable");
      });
    });
```

а вот что должно получаться в конечном итоге

```
<div class='clickable'>
  <div class="img-page">
  <img class="fix" src="...">
  <span>...</span>
  </div>
  //первый раз
  <div class="img-page">
  <img class="fix" src="...">
  <span>...</span>
  </div>
  //второй раз
  <div class="img-page">
  <img class="fix" src="...">
  <span>...</span>
  </div>
  //третий раз
</div>
```

что надо впихнуть в  этот `$.each()`? помогите люди добрые)

Comment: может просто $.each(data,function(i,item){}); ?

Comment: @eicto нет там основная инфа в массиве с названием data приходит так что все правильно

Comment: я думаю у вас не такой массив, как вы думаете, вот я тут набросал
http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/Dbayt/
скорее всего images у вас тоже массив внутри data, поэтому перебирать надо его.

Comment: @eicto, вы у меня решили экзамены принять или какую-то свою работу предлагаете сделать? давайте задачу целиком. озвучивайте сумму, дальше поговорим. Вы третий раз меня пытаетесь подловить и не выходит, и этому конца краю не видно похоже.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov нет, я просто пытаюсь понять почему вы так держитесь за представление в виде html, а что не выходит ? Задача... я просто развиваю задачу ТС, я легко могу сделать ее в объектном виде. но в html выглядит странно для меня.

Comment: я не держусь, я как раз показал, что ваш метод не единственный путь решения задачи. вы мне пытаетесь показать, что это не так и что ваш метод единственный верный. упорствуйте дальше. ваш метод - метод макарон - вызовов всяких разных методов друг из друга превращает три строчки в нечитаемую кашу. которую через неделю вы будете переписывать заново, потому что задача получила развитие, а иерархия элементов в голове уже не укладывается и как ее перестроить под новую структуру тоже непонятно.

Comment: так все наоборот, в результате собирания строки, вместо того чтобы просто добавить элемент к объекту программист вынужден искать место где он должен быть вставлен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функции работы с dom (что `append` или `appendTo`, что `html`) довольно тяжелые, поэтому соберите весь html в строку и один раз добавьте.

```
$.getJSON( url + "&callback=?",     
   function(data){
     var html = "";
     $.each(data.data, function(i,item){
       html += "<div class='img-page'>"
         +"<img class='fix' src='"+item.images.thumbnail.url+"'/>"
         +"</div>";
     });
     $(".clickable").append(html);
   }
});
```

Comment: глупости вы говорите. конкатенация строк у вас тяжелее перестройки дерева? не позорьтесь.

Comment: [тест](http://jsperf.com/html-render-vs-adding-each-time) в общем в данном случае, оно быстрее чаще получается чем медленнее, но тем не менее собирать строку html вместо объекта, все равно неправильно.

Comment: да, у меня тоже в тесте быстрее получилось строку собирать. и потом браузерописатели постоянно что-то оптимизируют, сегодня один вариант быстрее завтра другой варинат. не принципиально. я же говорил относительно стиля у ТС. так точно делать не стоит.

по поводу генерации строки. бывают случаи когда клонирование будет слишком не очевидным. мало ли что там с данными надо делать. может if'ов будет до полна, там добавлять - там не добавлять.

Comment: обычно как раз наоборот - есть объект с ним и работаем, например повесить собственный обработчик на каждый из этих элементов img при подходе через строку будет весьма проблематично

Comment: ну тут `on()` прекрасно справляется. противоречий тут нет.

Comment: вот как раз в этом примере попробуйте сделать по событию загрузки картинки какое-нибудь действие с on()... скажем получить ее размеры. ([вот этот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/Dbayt/7/) как решать будете с конкатинацией html ?)

Comment: Дак то же самое. Селекторы рулят, да. На все img сразу.

    ...
    $clickable.append(html);
    $('img').one('load', wrap_image)
      .each(function(){
         if(this.complete) $(this).load();
      });

Comment: там же не зря append, что случится после подгрузки второй порции ?

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте, попробуйте так

```
    $('.cackable').each(function(i,item){
        $(this).append("<div class='img-page'></div><img                 src='"+item.images.thumbnail.url+"' class='fix' />");
    });
```